# How to send a generic file to a remote Rest Service using JAVAX?

Tags: file, rest, service, send, javax

I am absolutely newer in REST services and solutions. I'm approaching now to these kind of technologies but I have to implement a method, a service, that take a JSON file I produce  in a folder in my classpath, and send it to a remote REST service of which I just know the URL.. I really don't know what I should do...

In my researches on the internet I found out this solution:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getFile() {
  File file = ... // Initialize this to the File path you want to serve.
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
      .build();
}
```

...that seems quite good for what I have to do, but as I'm not expert I really don't understand some things of it (I clarify that most of this following questions may be very stupid questions):

- assuming that this Response.ok() method is useful in my case, where I specify the remote REST service URL I have to reach?
- Is it possible to implement this need simply passing to the method the file object and the URL?

I really thank anyone who can answer my stupid questions.

Armando

Comment: The code snippet in your question is from a server, not from a client. You need a HTTP client library.